# Unique Order of Instance Binding

Tags: clips

I am attempting to trigger a rule exactly once for any unique pair of distinct instances.

A trivial example follows:

```
(defclass USER_THING (is-a USER))

(definstances KNOWN_THINGS
    (thing-a of USER_THING)
    (thing-b of USER_THING)
    (thing-c of USER_THING))

(defrule match-things
    ?thing0 <- (object (is-a USER_THING))
    ?thing1 <- (object (is-a USER_THING))
=>
    (printout t "-------" crlf)
    (printout t "thing0 " (instance-name ?thing0) crlf)
    (printout t "thing1 " (instance-name ?thing1) crlf))
```

Clearly, we'd expect the Cartesian product of `KNOWN_THINGS` with itself, which is exactly what we get:

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
-------
thing0 [thing-c]
thing1 [thing-c]
-------
thing0 [thing-c]
thing1 [thing-b]
-------
thing0 [thing-c]
thing1 [thing-a]
-------
thing0 [thing-a]
thing1 [thing-c]
-------
thing0 [thing-b]
thing1 [thing-c]
-------
thing0 [thing-b]
thing1 [thing-b]
-------
thing0 [thing-b]
thing1 [thing-a]
-------
thing0 [thing-a]
thing1 [thing-b]
-------
thing0 [thing-a]
thing1 [thing-a]
```

While my desired output is more akin to:

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
-------
thing0 [thing-a]
thing1 [thing-b]
-------
thing0 [thing-a]
thing1 [thing-c]
-------
thing0 [thing-b]
thing1 [thing-c]
```

I have experience with Apache Jena's forward-chaining inference system, wherein I'd simply add a rule clause to enforce an arbitrary ordering on the instance names:

```
(defrule match-things
    ?thing0 <- (object (is-a USER_THING))
    ?thing1 <- (object (is-a USER_THING))
    (> (str-compare (instance-name ?thing0) (instance-name ?thing1)) 0)
=>
    (printout t "-------" crlf)
    (printout t "thing0 " (instance-name ?thing0) crlf)
    (printout t "thing1 " (instance-name ?thing1) crlf))
```

This is not a proper CLIPS rule. What could I do to achieve my desired effect? I can add information to the instances (such as an arbitrary numeric or string identifier) as necessary to facilitate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the test conditional element:

```
(defrule match-things
    ?thing0 <- (object (is-a USER_THING))
    ?thing1 <- (object (is-a USER_THING))
    (test (> (str-compare (instance-name ?thing0) (instance-name ?thing1)) 0))
=>
    (printout t "-------" crlf)
    (printout t "thing0 " (instance-name ?thing0) crlf)
    (printout t "thing1 " (instance-name ?thing1) crlf))
```